# How do I get the count for numberOfRows when number of rows in each section varies?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to populate a tableview with entries from an XML file. So far I have parsed the XML file to a Struct and written the methods for titleForHeaderInSection and numberOfSections, but am struggling calculate numberOfRows for each section by counting the `<holiday>` entries in each `<calendarevent>`. I think my main struggle comes from not understanding how to use [section]. Here's what I've done so far:

I have parsed an xml file that has calendar dates and events like this. You'll see how the first calendarevent has 2 holiday and description entries but the second has 1. :

```
<calendar>
    <calendarevent>
        <month>October</month>
        <dateevent>2018 10 01</dateevent>
        <datenumber>01</datenumber>

        <holiday>First Holiday</holiday>
        <description>aaaaaaaaaa</description>

        <holiday>Second Holiday</holiday>
        <description>bbbbbbbbbb</description>

    </calendarevent>
    <calendarevent>
        <month>October</month>
        <dateevent>2018 10 10</dateevent>
        <datenumber>10</datenumber>

        <holiday>Third Holiday</holiday>
        <description>ccccccccccc</description>

    </calendarevent>
    .... and so on
```

To a struct that looks like this:

```
struct CalendarDates {
    struct CalendarEvents {
        var month = ""
        var eventdate = ""
        var eventdatenumber = ""
        var holiday = ""
        var description = ""
        }
}
```

Here is my XML Parser code:

```
class CalendarViewController {
    var myCalendarDatesFromStrut = [CalendarDates]()
    var myCalendarEventsFromStrut = [CalendarDates.CalendarEvents]()
}

extension CalendarViewController {
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        calendarEventsElementFromXML = elementName
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if data.count != 0 {
            switch calendarEventsElementFromXML
            {
            case "month": monthsFromXML = data
            case "dateevent": eventdatesFromXML = data
            case "datenumber": eventdatenumbersFromXML = data
            case "holiday": holidaysFromXML = data
            default: break
            }
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "calendarevent" {
            var myCalendarDates = CalendarDates.CalendarEvents()
            myCalendarDates.month = monthsFromXML
            myCalendarDates.eventdate = eventdatesFromXML
            myCalendarDates.eventdatenumber = eventdatenumbersFromXML
            myCalendarDates.holiday = holidaysFromXML
            myCalendarEventsFromStrut.append(myCalendarDates)
        }
    }
}
```

So after parsing XML and appending it to the struct, I start getting the values for the tableview.

Each section is made of one `<calendarevent>` if the `<month>` is the same as current Date month. The XML has `<calendarevent>` from other months so I don't want all of them. I check if the current month is == month in XML, if it is, then I count #of dateevents for numberOfSections and format the dateevents to become the titles of those sections.

Then each row in a section represents one `<holiday>` in the corresponding `<calendarevent>`.

```
extension CalendarViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    //Calculates # of <dateevents> in current month
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    let currentMonthShown = formatter.string(from: selectedDate)
    let allEventsInVisibleMonth = myCalendarEventsFromStrut.filter({ $0.month == currentMonthShown }).map {$0.eventdate}.count
    return allEventsInVisibleMonth
    }

    // Prints <dateevent> reformatted as section header
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    let currentMonthShown = formatter.string(from: selectedDate)
    let allEventsInVisibleMonth = myCalendarEventsFromStrut.filter({ $0.month == currentMonthShown }).map {$0.eventdate}
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let eventStringsToDate = allEventsInVisibleMonth.map{ formatter.date(from: $0) }
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    let eventDatesBackToString = eventStringsToDate.map{ formatter.string(from: $0 as! Date )}
    return eventDatesBackToString[section]
    }
```

Now, each row in a section needs to represent one `<holiday>` in the corresponding `<calendarevent>` - here's where I'm stuck.

For tableview's numberOfRowsInSection, I need to count # of `<holiday>` entries are in each `<calendarevent>` and show that # rows in each section. Then print the  in cellForRowAt. Could someone give me a hint for the logic here?

Here is what I tried and where I'm failing specifically:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
     let currentMonthShown = formatter.string(from: selectedDate)
    let allEventsInMonth = myCalendarEventsFromStrut.filter({ $0.month == currentMonthShown }).map {$0.holiday}

    return allEventsInMonth.count //This gets me same number of rows in all sections = total # of events in current month.

//I'm struggling to figure out how to get # of events at a particular section, so I can make that the # of rows
    }
```

Comment: Seems your `section` is not clearly defined. What do you want to show in each section? In your current `numberOfSections(in:)`, your return the number of calendar events in a specific month. Which means each section contains one calendar event, is that really what you intend? Please clarify what you want to show in each section.

Comment: In numberOfSections, I check if <month> is the same as current Date month, then find the <dateevents> and show as many sections as there are <dateevents> in current month. Then I make the <dateevents> the headers for the sections. For numberOfRows, I want to get # of <holidays> per each <dateevents> and show that # of rows. So in the example XML, I have 2 <holiday> entries for that <month> or<dateentry> so I want 2 rows. @OOPer

Comment: Ok, some things got clear: **each _section_ is made of one <calendarevent>** / **each _row_ in a _section_ represents one <holiday> in the corresponding <calendarevent>**, right?

Comment: @OOPer yes that is it. I was using the <month> to calculate numOfsection because I need to get the months from the current month only and not all the <calendarevents> which include entries from other months. And yes, each row in a section represents one <holiday> in each corresponding <calendarevent>

Comment: Then you may need to change your definition of `CalendarEvents` as it can hold only one _holiday_, it also requires a big update of your `XMLParserDelegate` methods. You should better include into your question the two things I wrote above. Someone would answer faster than me, with some clear definitions given.

Comment: @OOPer Thank you. I added that to the original question.  As a beginner, half the time I'm not sure what to ask and I appreciate you taking this time and helping me improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the XML may contain multiple `holiday` element inside a single `calendarevent`, so you need to update your `CalendarEvents` to be able to hold multiple holidays.

```
struct Holiday {
    var title: String = ""
    var description: String = ""
}

//You should better avoid plural form for something which represents a single object
struct CalendarEvent {
    var month: String = ""
    var eventdate: String = ""
    var eventdatenumber: String = ""
    //Better use plural form for the name representing multiple objects
    var holidays: [Holiday] = []
}
```

(I removed the outer struct `CalendarDates` as I cannot find any reason you need nested types. Also I recommend you to avoid plural form to name something which represents a single object.)

---

To parse your XML using the structs, you need some more properties to be used in `XMLParserDelegate`:

```
class CalendarViewController: UIViewController {
    //`myCalendarEventsFromStrut` is too long and `FromStrut` does not make sense
    var myCalendarEvents: [CalendarEvent] = []

    //Properties needed for parsing your XML
    var textCurrentlyParsed: String? = nil
    var monthFromXML: String = ""
    var dateeventFromXML: String = ""
    var datenumberFromXML: String = ""
    var holidaysFromXML: [Holiday] = []

    //Your table view shows some selected evnets in `myCalendarEvents`,
    //To improve response, you should beter keep the filtered result, when `selectedDate` is updated.
    var selectedDate: Date? {
        didSet {
            if let date = selectedDate {
                let currentMonthShown = monthFormatter.string(from: date)
                allEventsInVisibleMonth = myCalendarEvents.filter({ $0.month == currentMonthShown })
            } else {
                allEventsInVisibleMonth = [] //Or you prefer `allEventsInVisibleMonth = myCalendarEvents`?
            }
        }
    }
    var allEventsInVisibleMonth: [CalendarEvent] = []

    //You may have this sort of constants somewhere, this is just an example
    let TheCellID = "cell" //Change this according to your actual setups

    //
    // Date formatters.
    //  Better keep distinct DateFormaters accoding to the format to avoid simple mistakes
    //

    let monthFormatter: DateFormatter = {
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
        return formatter
    }()

    let dateeventFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
        return formatter
    }()

    let sectionHeaderFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()

    //...
}
```

(The code above has some addition to write some example of `UITableViewDataSource` methods.)

With the properties above you can write your `XMLParserDelegate` methods as follows:

```
extension CalendarViewController: XMLParserDelegate {
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        switch elementName {
        case "month", "dateevent", "datenumber", "holiday", "description":
            //Reset the text content for the element
            textCurrentlyParsed = ""
        case "calendarevent":
            //Reset all variables which may contain the result of previous element
            monthFromXML = ""
            dateeventFromXML = ""
            datenumberFromXML = ""
            holidaysFromXML = []
        case "calendar":
            //Can be ignored
            break
        default:
            print("Unexpected start tag:", elementName)
            break
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        //`parser(_:foundCharacters:)` may be called several times for a seemingly single text content,
        //So you need to add the `string` to the currently parsed text
        textCurrentlyParsed? += string
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        switch elementName {
        case "calendarevent":
            var calendarEvent = CalendarEvent()
            calendarEvent.month = monthFromXML
            calendarEvent.eventdate = dateeventFromXML
            calendarEvent.eventdatenumber = datenumberFromXML
            calendarEvent.holidays = holidaysFromXML
            myCalendarEvents.append(calendarEvent)
        case "month":
            if let parsedText = textCurrentlyParsed?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
                monthFromXML = parsedText
            }
        case "dateevent":
            if let parsedText = textCurrentlyParsed?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
                dateeventFromXML = parsedText
            }
        case "datenumber":
            if let parsedText = textCurrentlyParsed?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
                datenumberFromXML = parsedText
            }
        case "holiday":
            if let parsedText = textCurrentlyParsed?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
                var holiday = Holiday()
                holiday.title = parsedText
                holidaysFromXML.append(holiday)
            }
            break
        case "description":
            if
                let parsedText = textCurrentlyParsed?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
                case let lastIndexOfHoliday = holidaysFromXML.count - 1, lastIndexOfHoliday >= 0
            {
                //You need to modify the last entry in `holidaysFromXML`
                holidaysFromXML[lastIndexOfHoliday].description = parsedText
            }
        default:
            print("Unexpected end tag:", elementName)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

(If you have no need to `trim` the texts, the code above can be simplified, a little.)

---

With those codes included, your `UITableViewDataSource` methods would look like this:

```
extension CalendarViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return allEventsInVisibleMonth.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allEventsInVisibleMonth[section].holidays.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let eventForTheSection = allEventsInVisibleMonth[indexPath.section]
        let holidayForTheRow = eventForTheSection.holidays[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TheCellID, for: indexPath)
        //... setup the cell using `eventForTheSection` and `holidayForTheRow`
        return cell
    }

    // Prints <dateevent> reformatted as section header
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let eventForTheSection = allEventsInVisibleMonth[section]
        if let eventdateAsDate = dateeventFormatter.date(from: eventForTheSection.eventdate) {
            return sectionHeaderFormatter.string(from: eventdateAsDate)
        } else {
            return "Broken eventdate: \(eventForTheSection.eventdate)"
        }
    }

}
```

(NOT tested, you may need some fixes.)

Generally, `UITableViewDataSource` methods can be called very often, so you should implement them efficiently.

So, creating a filtered array at each call is not recommended.
You should better update `allEventsInVisibleMonth` only when:

- `myCalendarEvents` is updated (not included in my codes above)
- `selectedDate` is updated (`didSet` in `selectedDate` will do it)

---

A little bit long, but I believe it's worth trying.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, esp the explanations. Thank you so much! A question for my own understanding: In the XML Parsing, I see a line that says "case let lastIndexOfHoliday = holidaysFromXML.count - 1, lastIndexOfHoliday >= 0". I don't really understand what that does? I see how you first parse CalendarEvents and then Holidays. In CalendarEvents, it seems that you don't check if there is last entry, but in the Holidays you do?

Comment: A second question: I want to get better at reusing like you have with textCurrentlyParsed += but it looks so efficient. Do you know of any good tutorials/guides to get better at this? I'm still writing out every long form and I want to become more efficient

Comment: @smarttrams, A1: (first)`if-case` was [introduced in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW326), but not much described in Swift books. I tests pattern matching like `switch-case` and `if-case-let` establishes a new local variable when matched. In my code above `case let lastIndexOfHoliday` matches any pattern, it just established a new variable `lastIndexOfHoliday`. `,` is just a separator between the condition clauses in the `if` statement.

Comment: @smarttrams, A1: (latter) `holiday` element just creates an instance of `Holiday` and add it to `holiday`. Adding is an always-suceeds operation, so no need to check. But `description` element modifies the last created `Holiday`, so checking is needed if there really exists at least one `Holiday`.

Comment: @smarttrams, A2: It's hard to say such things, as I have been writing codes for more than 40 years, and you would not like to spend 40 years learning programming. Recently, you can find many resources on the web. Find as many good codes as you can and learn from them.